# Convert data from file into an array of integers (C)

Tags: c, arrays, text, duplicates

i have the following data in a txt. And i want to extract every number of the 4th column into an array without duplicate numbers

```
[1] [0] 1   50
[1] [2] 1   6

[1] [13]    4   8-35-38
```

The output should be something like this: [50,6,8,35,38]

How can i store them into an array?

Comment: assuming you didn't mean to write 6 in your example array twice?

Comment: @Jake they for sure meant 36.

Comment: @Cipher you can read each file line with fgets, then parse them either with sscanf or scanning the string with a pointer. Finally, add each found number in the array, checking for duplicates and inserting it so that the array is always sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my idea, hope it can help you.

You can use fgets info from this file

```
char line[256];
int first, second, third;
char forth[256];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    printf("%s", line); 
    sscanf(line, "[%d] [%d] %d   %s\n", &first, &second, &third, forth)
}
```

Then using the `strtok` and `atoi` (convert string to int, you can also use `strtol` or `sscanf`) function to get all number of each line.

```
char* token = strtok(line, "-"); 

    while (token != NULL) { 
        int i = atoi(token)
        token = strtok(NULL, "-"); 
    }
```

Copy the `i` value to an array.

Then create a function for eliminating the duplicate number, for example:

```
uint32_t delete_duplicate_value (uint32_t * list, uint32_t size) {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (uint32_t j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
            if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                for (uint32_t k = j; k < size; k++) {
                    list[k] = list[k + 1];
                }
                size--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean for `i` skips some values